# Default Value for Jeffrey ways - Generator package

Tags: laravel, generator

I tried to search a lot but i couldn't find how can we pass on default value to the generator. It can be time saver. FOr now I manually change the values in the generated files

second is there a way through which we can pass a different name for the primary key then what gets generated automatically - id. I would like to have AdminId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this? `--fields="name:string:default('John Doe'), bio:text:nullable"`

It's in the documentation on Github:
https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators

Comment: By default the command creates the primary key 'id' can i somehow have 'AdminId'

when i pass it in the command as --fields="name:increment, email:..." it creates a new line in the migration file for this but the id still persists there